# C# How to set 0x.. in Byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I want to make a `Byte[]` like this one:

```
Byte[] data = { 0x10, 0x02, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x25, 0x23, 0x05, 0xb1, 0x10, 0x03 };
```

But I have to get these from the user. I tired with Console.ReadLine and the convert to int or Byte or anything but non of them work because x is not a number.

The question is how can I get the `0x10` for example or `0x25` from the user and set in a `Byte[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `Split` the input string into chunks `Convert` each chunk to byte, and finally materialize them `ToArray`:

```
 // You can let user input the array as a single string 
 // Test/Demo; in real life it should be 
 // string source = Console.ReadLine();
 string source = "0x10, 0x02, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x25, 0x23, 0x05, 0xb1, 0x10, 0x03"; 

 byte[] result = source
   .Split(new char[] {' ', ':', ',', ';', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 
   .Select(item => Convert.ToByte(item, 16))
   .ToArray();
```

Let's represent the array back as string:

```
 string test = string.Join(", ", result
   .Select(item => "0x" + item.ToString("x2"))); 

 // "0x10, 0x02, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x25, 0x23, 0x05, 0xb1, 0x10, 0x03"
 Console.Write(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep storing bytes in a loop, I would suggest you to create a list before the loop as an auxiliary variable.

```
List<byte> mylist = new List<byte>();
```

Then you can scan the inputs from the command line and store them using something like this:

```
mylist.Add(Convert.ToByte(my_input, 16));
```

At the end you can simply convert your list to array

```
mylist.ToArray();
```